# Recording real JDBC connection and producing Jooq mocking file

Tags: jdbc, mocking, jooq

https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/3.1.x/org/jooq/tools/jdbc/MockFileDatabase.html

Am I expected to write this mock file manually?

I need to mock a sequence of queries and results, and it's expect to be updated so I don't want to fix it constantly.

I'm working on a recording connection since I couldn't find any, It's not complex but It just doesn't make sense to me that Jooq libraries don't provide it.

Answer (score 1):

> Am I expected to write this mock file manually?

There's no "best" way to write this file. It is what it is and does what it does.

> I need to mock a sequence of queries and results, and it's expect to be updated so I don't want to fix it constantly.

As mentioned throughout the documentation of these mocking features, you should be *very careful* if you really want to implement such a mock database (i.e. an entire database product), or if you don't better proceed with integration testing your actual database, e.g. using [testcontainers](https://www.testcontainers.org). From how I read your question, you're at the point where you should switch.

> I'm working on a recording connection since I couldn't find any, It's not complex but It just doesn't make sense to me that Jooq libraries don't provide it.

A recording connection sounds interesting indeed, but it would depend on so many things, including the exact sequence of operations in your client application that lead to this exact sequence of queries. Besides, when recording, there might be two consecutive executions of an identical query text that results in different result sets. After all, recording would happen against a *real* database product. Whereas this `MockFileDatabase` is nowhere near a simulation of a real database product.

It's a simple tool for simple mocks. What you're looking for is actual integration testing.

#### To answer your question:

If you *need* to use this mock API, then you need to write your file manually.